# Highcharts' Highstocks inputEnabled onchange event for an api call

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts' Highstocks date input fields, is there a way to create an onchange event to make an api call for a date range outside of existing bounds ?

```
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart(element[0], {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        height: 300
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showInNavigator: true
          }
    },
    yAxis: {
        opposite: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [],
        inputEnabled: true
    },
   series: {}
});

angular.forEach(data, function(key, value) {
    chart.addSeries({
        "color" : key.color,
        "name": key.name,
        "data": key.data,
        "z" : key.units
    });
});
```

The variable "data" here has a data from **25th February to 26th February**. In what way can I change the input field of highcharts to create an onchange event or something so that I can make an API call ? e.g. I want to make an API call to see data from **23rd Feb to 26th Feb**, after the chart is loaded.

Comment: Add some code what you have done. And what do you mean by _outside of existing bounds_

Comment: Hi @Deep3015, I just updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi, It does not allow, but you can do it with JavaScript. Here I subtract 5 day from start day.check this http://jsfiddle.net/rtw90rsv/

Comment: Thanks man... It was of much help... :)